# AZURE AD ADAL "error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to Authenticate using AZURE AD. I took the java client code from the git [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect][1].

I am able to make the authorize call and get the Authorization code. By passing the authorization code to get the access token using the acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode method from the oauth2 jar. Here I am getting the below error.

> "error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid.

How to pass the grant_type=authorization_code to the acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode method?

How to check the post request which got fired? I am not able to see it in the network section of the chrome?

Below is the code:

```
        String authCode = authorizationCode.getValue();
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId,
                clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext context;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {

            ThreadFactory factory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
            service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory);

            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant + "/", true,
                    service);

            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context
                    .acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(
                            currentUri), credential, null);
```

The post request should be:
String redirectUrl = authority
                        + this.tenant
                        + "/oauth2/v2.0/token?**p=b2c_1_abcd**&**grant_type=authorization_code&resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.windows.net**&redirect_uri="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(**REDIRECT_URL**, "UTF-8");

Not sure how to provide the information which is in bold.

Comment: By passing scope=offline while requesting the authorization code, I am able to get the refresh token. Do I need to make any such additional changes to get the access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT after more info**

If you are using v2 endpoints, you can't use ADAL.

If you have registered your app in the v2 dev portal, you need to register your app via Azure Portal's Azure AD interface. And then make sure your Azure AD URLs do not include v2.0.

---

To get a token with authorization code, you use `acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4jsample/BasicFilter.java#L268-L270):

```
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context
                .acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(
                        currentUri), credential, null);
```

You will not see the request in Chrome because it goes from your web server to Azure AD. The browser is not a part of the chain. *And that's a good thing since we are passing the client secret to Azure AD*. You can use tools like Fiddler to monitor the traffic.

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to receive the authorization code to the question?

Comment: @krishnapriyanukala See my edit. If you are trying to use v2 endpoints with ADAL, it will not work.

Comment: Just to add, instead of ADAL for v2, you can use the new MSAL library.  Check out the [code samples](https://aka.ms/aadv2)

Comment: MSAL library supports java webapplication @DanielDobalian

Comment: @krishnapriyanukala it does not, my mistake. Didn't see it was Java. I've written a [java mvc app w/ Azure AD v2 integrated](https://github.com/danieldobalian/AADv2JavaMVC) that may help.

Comment: @DanielDobalian Thanks for the sample. By using the above code I am able to get the access token, but when graph API call happens I am getting the below error                                                                      
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure."

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Could you check if an answer already exists? If not, make another question.